# How to generate Java code for MS Dynamics CRM 2011 Service

Tags: java, apache-axis, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011

I tried to generate Java code using 'Apache Axis2 Tools Code Generator Wizard plugin for Eclipse 1.6.2', and got an error below

> A error occurred while completing process - java.lang.InterruptedException: org.apache.axis2.wsdl.codegen.CodeGenerationException: java.lang.RuntimeException: can't serialize the policy ...

Any idea?

Comment: Are you following the example from the SDK?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We use apache ant in our Development for generating stub from the Webservice

It is good and easy to use.

Here is the link
     http://ant.apache.org/